# Greens function derivative

Tags: greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

I´ve given a green's function defined as $$ G_N(\vec{x},\vec{x}') = \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}+\frac{1}{4 \pi}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}_s'|} $$ with $$y_s=(y_1,y_2,-y_3)$$ on $$H\subset\mathbb{R}^3 ;H=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R},x_3>0\} ; \partial H=\{(x_1,x_2,0),x_1,x_2 \in\mathbb{R}\}$$

Now I want to show that $$\Delta_x G_N(\vec{x},\vec{x}')=-\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')$$

If I do the calculation

$$ \Delta_x G_N(\vec{x},\vec{x}') = \frac{1}{4\pi}(\Delta_x \frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}+\Delta_x\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}_s'|} )$$ it results in

$$\Delta_xG_N(\vec{x},\vec{x}')=-\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')+\delta(x_1-y_1')\delta(x_2-y_2')\delta(x_3+y_3')$$ because of $$\Delta_x\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}=-4\pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')$$

My question is: Why the $$\delta(x_1-y_1')\delta(x_2-y_2')\delta(x_3+y_3')$$ term is getting zero?

Comment: Hi B4ckflip. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Does the condition you imposed in $x_3$ also apply to $y_3$? Because if $y_3 > 0$ then the Dirac Delta on $(x-y)$ is zero everywhere in $H$.

Comment: Note if you edit a question to clarify it, it comes up for consideration for reopening - there's a voting process for that you need to wait patiently and let happen.